# How to select all child checkboxes using HTML5 data attributes in Lighting

Tags: lightning, javascript, aura

I have some code in my Lightning app which displays regions and countries beneath them using the code below (sorry its a bit messy I know):

```
    <div class="slds-checkbox">
        <input
           aura:id="inputComponent"
           onchange="{!c.selectoptionvalue}" 
           type="checkbox" 
           id="{! v.is_region ? 'checkbox-' + v.label  : 'checkbox-' + v.value}"
           data-parent_region="{! v.is_region ? '' : v.region }"
           data-region="{! v.is_region ? v.region : '' }"
           value="{!v.value}" />
        <label class="{! v.is_region ? 'slds-checkbox__label item-region' : 'slds-checkbox__label item-country'}" for="{! v.is_region ? 'checkbox-' + v.label  : 'checkbox-' + v.value}">
            <span class="slds-checkbox_faux"></span>
            <span class="slds-form-element__label">{!v.label}</span>
        </label>
    </div>
```

You will notice that each checkbox has some HTML5 data attributes attached, the `parent_region` is populated when the item is a Country, and the `region` is populated when its a Region item.

The idea is when a region item is selected (using the `region` attribute), I can find all matching `parent-region` items to also check/uncheck.

But I'm stuck at the first hurdle as I don't know how to access the HTMl attributes.

This is what I have in my JS controller which returns undefined:

```
    selectoptionvalue : function(component, event, helper) {
        var inputComponentDataAttrib = component.find("inputComponent").getElement().get("v.HTMLAttributes").parent_region;
        console.log('parent region clicked: ' + inputComponentDataAttrib);
....
```

Comment: have you tried to access var inputComponentDataAttrib = component.find("inputComponent").getElement().dataset.parent_region;?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i just got refer from [dataset](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLElement/dataset)
here. and i removed '_' in your attribute " data-parent_region" replaced with '-' please try below tested code.

controller.js

```
selectoptionvalue : function(component, event, helper) {

    var parentreg = event.currentTarget.dataset.parentRegion;
    var reg = event.currentTarget.dataset.region;
    console.log(parentreg );
    console.log(reg );
},
```